# Geometric sum with complex exponent

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-series, exponential-sum

I've encountered an infinite geometric sum while working a question:
$$
(1 - e^{-6wi}) \sum_{0}^{\infty} {e^{-iwn}}
$$

According to the answer sheet, this should resolve to:
$$
\frac{(1 - e^{-6wi})}{(1 - e^{-wi})}
$$

The context of this question is applying a Discrete Fourier Transform on the signal *x[n] = u[n] - u[n-6]* where *u[n]* is the step function.

I'm having a hard time understanding this step, could someone elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given it some thought and managed to wiggle my way to the solution using the Z-transform rather than geometric progression.

We know the Z-Transform of a unit complex number is equivalent to the Discrete Time Fourier Transform.

Hence:

*x[n] = u[n] - u[n-6]*

Applying the Z-transform gives us:
$$\frac{1 - z^{-6}}{1 - z^{-1}}$$

Setting *|z| = 1* gives us the answer we're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to have some doubt indeed

$$\sum_{0}^{\infty} {e^{-iwn}}=\sum_{0}^{\infty} {(e^{-iw})^n}=\frac1{1-e^{-iw}}$$

only holds if $|e^{-iw}|<1$.

Therefore for $\omega\in \mathbb R$ the identity doesn't hold and for $\omega =x+iy$ we have

$$e^{-iw}=e^{-i(x+iy)}=e^y \cdot e^{ix}$$

and in this case the identity holds for $|e^y \cdot e^{ix}|=|e^y|<1$ that is $y<0$.

Comment: The problem is wolframalpha claims the series diverges [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum+e%5E%28-i*n%29%2C+n+%3D+0+to+infinity)

Comment: @Threnody Wolfram is assuming $i$ as the imaginary. What is it in your context?

Comment: Yes that's quite right, forgot to mention that. Context is Discrete Fourier Transform of the signal _x[n] = u[n] - u[n-6]_

Comment: @Threnody for $\omega$ real the identity doesn't hold.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just in case I'll keep the question open for a while since maybe there could be a different approach to get to the same answer.

Comment: @Threnody Yes of course! That's fine.